# gmaps4rails1.5.1-Geocoding not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Location added to table. But missing latitude/longitude. So no marker added to the map.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :priority,:addr,:presence=>true
  validates :priority,:numericality=>{:greater_than_or_equal_to =>1,:less_than_or_equal_to =>6}
  default_scope :order=>'priority'
  acts_as_gmappable :lat=>'lat',:lng=>'lng'

  def gmaps4rails_address
    self.addr
  end

  def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "<h4>Target priority: #{priority}</h4>" << "<h4>Address: #{addr}</h4>" << "<h4>Latitude: #{lat}</h4>" << "<h4>Longitude: #{lng}</h4>"
  end

 def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
  {
      "picture" => "/images/#{priority%7}.jpg",
      "width" => "30",
      "height" => "30"
  }
  end
end
```

[image: After new location added]

Comment: Does this happen on create or when you edit the record? I can't reproduce...

Comment: Both. Will try creating new project. With different columns.

Comment: Say you save the `user` object. What's the value of `user.gmaps` ?

Comment: location.gmaps=true. gmaps=true as default for all locations in migration. So it automatically applies to all seed/manually created locations.

Comment: then you have your answer: geocoding isn't triggered when gmaps == true... did you set this as default value? why?

Comment: Figured all locations would need gmaps=true to be placed on map. Will remove the default config.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10789/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-daniel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `gmaps` to `false` to trigger geocoding (as the doc tells)